# Adobe Flash send file to PHP

Tags: php, forms, file, actionscript-2

I have flash file that sends file to php but I cannot debug it. e.g. `var_dump($_FILE)` shows nothing! However when I run script it does work and upload file to server.

This is part of action script.

```
listener.onSelect = function (selectedFile, bytesTotal) {
    browse._visible = false;
    uploadBtn._visible = true;
    var _loc3 = new Date();
    sendTimeFLASH = _loc3.getTime();
    sendTime = sendTimeFLASH;
    totalId = flashimgID + ":" + selectedFile.name;
    flash.external.ExternalInterface.call("funName", totalId);
    statusArea.text = details.text = "";
    txt_mc.statusArea.text = txt_mc.statusArea.text + selectedFile.name;
    videoFile_name = selectedFile.name;
    var _loc4 = imageFile.size;
    d = _loc4 / 1000;
    txt.text = selectedFile.name + "(" + Math.round(d) + "Kb): now click Upload to proceed";
    var _loc1 = new LoadVars();
    _loc1.imgPHP = flashimgID;
    _loc1.imgName = selectedFile.name;
    _loc1.timePHP = sendTime;
    _loc1.sendAndLoad("page.php", _loc1, "POST");
    imageFile.upload("page.php?id=" + flashimgID);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

file is not sent in $_FILES from flash, but as a byte array.
save it like this:

```
$data = file('php://stdin');
if(file_put_contents('/path/to/file',$data)){
    echo 1;
}else{
    echo 0;
}
```

Comment: Its originally previous developer code, and in php file he had $_FILES['Dataset']['name'] for example so i think it did work. It did work and there was no code that looks like yours.

Comment: my experience with flash is limited. i just know that some of the api's i've set up for flash apps had to be coded this way. in your specific case, i have no real clue.

Comment: http://strongphpsolutions.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/flash-php-upload-actionscript-2/ he has similar thing to mine but yet he uses $_files too